# How to show that the language $L = \{a^n , n \geq 10000 \text{ and $n$ is prime number}\}$ is not context-free using closure property?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

I proved $L' = \{a^n \mid n \text{ is a prime number}\}$ is not context-free language using the pumping lemma.
But I couldn't derive that $L$ is not a context-free language by using closure properties of context-free languages and the result that $L'$ is not context-free.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Two possibilities:

(1) You can use the fact that [a context-free language on a one-letter alphabet is regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40791/proving-that-any-cf-language-over-a-1-letter-alphabet-is-regular).

(2) You can also observe that $L = L' \cap K$ where $K$ is the set of all words of length $\geqslant 10000$.